# How to use GoRouter inside of a widget

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I want to have some navigation inside of my dialog. In the past I just used a Navigator widget for that:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: routeHome,
        onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
    );
  }
```

But now I switched to go_router. Is there any way I can accomplish the same with go_router? To have a separate Navigation inside of my dialog?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: You can make use of ShellRoute. There is even a stageful version of it. Just check the latest docs.